# How can you rotate a procedural material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm modeling our church sanctuary to assist in a lighting design and I am reusing a procedural wood material from the wood pews to kind of simulate the laminated beams that hold up the roof, but those beams are vertical, not horizontal like the pews.

I've tried just adjusting rotation in the vector transforms, and I've tried switching the scaling to favor the z-axis rather than the x-axis.  Neither attempt has worked.

(This procedural wood is courtesy of an old thread on [blenderartists.org](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?296800-Free-Procedural-wood-with-Cycles-Blend-file-attached&highlight=rotate%20procedural))

[image: procedural wood]

The horizontally striped beam is the test beam (on the right, in the light)
[image]

Comment: Try setting the mapping node to *Texture* at the top. It might be more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure how that makes things more intuitive.  If you could explain that would help me with my understanding of the mapping node (I have been RTFMing :)  I reset the scale and rotation values to 1 and 0, respectively, and started from scratch.  It's not realistic yet, since the wood grain doesn't bend with the wood, but I've got some ideas to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @gandalf3's suggestion above, I switched to having my values affect the texture, restarted all values from scale of 1 and rotation of 0, and then started playing with them until I got something that's sort of acceptable.  It really helped to partition my screen so the node editor was large but above it was the 3D View wherein I had isolated my beam (Numpad /) and had the 3D View set for "Rendered view" That allowed me to see the effect of my changes quite quickly.

[image: Node Tree]

[image: Sample Beam using procedural wood]